# CanCan Rails Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancan

I am creating REST API and also using Authorization in REST API. Whenever a user is not authorized for a action it redirects to home page using the following code

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to "/", :alert => exception.message
end
```

For Rest API method, I don't want to be redirected to this page on unauthorized access. Instead, I want to display json

> {"Error_msg": "Not Authorized"}.

My controller has following code:

```
authorize_resource :class => false, :only => [:create_or_update]
```

where `create_or_update` is an action(method) on which I want to check authorization.

My ability.rb has following code in `editor` role

```
can :create_or_update, :topology
```

Can someone help me not getting redirected to  home page only for this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
 if exception.action.to_s == "create_or_update"
   err ={}
   err[:error_id] = "AUTHORIZATION_ERROR"
   err[:error_msg] = exception.message
   render json: err, status: 403
 else
   redirect_to "/", :alert => exception.message
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using respond_to

```
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render(json: {"Error_msg": "Not Authorized"}, status: :forbidden)}
      format.html{
        redirect_to "/", :alert => exception.message
      }
    end
  end
```